# Spring: Adding autowired property to list

Tags: java, spring

I have a bean defined in xml configuration as:

```
<bean id="dataService" class="com.sample.DataService" />
```

In another class it is used as resource and put in a list.

```
@Resource(name = "dataService")
private Driver dataService;

private List<Driver> drivers = new ArrayList<Driver>() {
        {
            drivers.add(dataService);
        }
};
```

I am getting `NullPointer Exception` on line `drivers.add(dataService);` I thought dataService should not be null as it is autowired. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can populate your collection in the appropriate [callback](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html):

```
@Resource(name = "dataService")
private Driver dataService;

private List<Driver> drivers;

@PostConstruct
public void setup(){
    drivers = new ArrayList<Driver>();
    drivers.add(dataService);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The autowire-int is done after the bean is created.

Try to use constructor injection and add the bean to the list in the constrictor.

```
private Driver dataService;

private List<Driver> drivers;
@Autowired
public MyBean(Driver driver){
    drivers = new ArrayList<Driver>();
    drivers.add(driver);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't getting the `NullPointerException` because dataService is `null`.  You're getting the `NullPointerException` because you're trying to add a value to a `List` that has not be initialized.  You are assigning a new, anonymously subclassed instance of ArrayList to `drivers` while you're referencing `drivers` from the subclass.  If you dropped "drivers" from the `drivers.add(dataService)` line, you would not get the `NullPointerException`.

However you're still left with the fact `dataService` is `null` until the object is initialized using the default constructor or a parameterized constructor using dependency injection.  Here's how I would do it:

```
@Autowired
private List<Driver> drivers;
```

Spring will automatically create the `List` from `all` available beans of the expected type.  No need for `@PostConstruct` or other callbacks.